# read specific data in CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have written a code that reads the product given as an input and gives the output of the price of the product

**data.csv file**

```
1, 4.00, teddy_bear
1, 8.00, baby_powder
2, 5.00, teddy_bear
2, 6.50, baby_powder
3, 4.00, pampers_diapers
3, 8.00, johnson_wipes
4, 5.00, johnson_wipes
4, 2.50, cotton_buds
5, 4.00, bath_towel
5, 8.00, scissor
6, 5.00, scissor
6, 6.00, bath_towel, cotton_balls, powder_puff
```

**python code**

```
import csv

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    usrid = []
    price = []
    product = []
    for row in readCSV:
        usrid.append(row[0])
        price.append(row[1])
        product.append(row[2])

    askProduct = raw_input('What Product do you wish to know the price of?:')
    abc = product.index(askProduct)
    thePrice = price[abc]
    print ('the price of product',askProduct, 'is', thePrice)
```

**error generated**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Desktop/program.py", line 15, in <module>
abc = product.index(askProduct)
ValueError: 'teddy_bear' is not in list
```

**following output is needed**

```
Program Input
program data.csv teddy_bear baby_powder

Expected Output

=> 2(userid), 11.5(addition of two products)
```

Comment: If you print off your lists, you will notice that the product names have spaces in front of them. This is the reason you cannot search for them correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code not only fails but the space, you also miss the last products comma separated. here is my suggestion

```
import csv

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    usrid = []
    price = []
    product = []
    for row in readCSV:
        # tmp_products =  row[2].split().strip()
        for the_product in row[2::]:
            usrid.append(row[0])
            price.append(row[1])
            product.append(the_product.strip())

askProduct = raw_input('What Product do you wish to know the price of?: ')
abc = product.index(askProduct)
thePrice = price[abc]
print ('the price of product',askProduct, 'is', thePrice)
```

And also you have same product with different price so the code may be like:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    usrid = []
    price = []
    product = []
    for row in readCSV:
        # tmp_products =  row[2].split().strip()
        for the_product in row[2::]:
            usrid.append(row[0].strip())
            price.append(row[1].strip())
            product.append(the_product.strip())

askProduct = raw_input('What Product do you wish to know the price of?: ')
abc = [i for i, x in enumerate(product) if x == askProduct]
thePrice = [ price[p] for p in abc]
print ('the price of product',askProduct, 'is', thePrice)
```

**UPDATE**

```
import csv

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)
    usrid = []
    price = []
    product = []
    for row in readCSV:
        for the_product in row[2::]:
            usrid.append(row[0])
            price.append(float(row[1]))
            product.append(the_product)

askProduct = raw_input('What Product do you wish to know the price of?: ')
abc = [i for i, x in enumerate(product) if x == askProduct]
thePrice = [price[p] for p in abc]
print ('the price of product',askProduct, 'is', min(thePrice))
```

Comment: how to add the two price of the product then, it gives the result in a string for eg: the price of product1 teddy_bear is ['4.00', '5.00']
           the price of product2 baby_powder is ['8.00','6.50'] 
i want to add the two products product1 and product2 and give the miniumum amount

Comment: to have it in a number form you only have to change `price.append(row[1].strip())` by `price.append(float(row[1].strip()))` and then to get the minimum only use `min(thePrice)` or `min( [ price[p] for p in abc])`

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra space in your CSV, so your product is actually `" teddy_bear"`. Python's `csv.reader()` allows you to tell it to ignore extra spaces around separators with the `skipinitialspace` argument:

```
csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of the space before each cell in the row. Since the delimiter is '," and your data file has a space after each ","

```
import csv

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    usrid = []
    price = []
    product = []
    for row in readCSV:
        usrid.append(row[0].strip())
        price.append(row[1].strip())
        product.append(row[2].strip())

    askProduct = raw_input('What Product do you wish to know the price      of?:')
    abc = product.index(askProduct)
    thePrice = price[abc]
    print ('the price of product',askProduct, 'is', thePrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check exactly how your lists are composed, it is very possible that your product array is something like `[' teddy_bear', ' baby_powder']`, etc due to the way the CSV is constructed. One way to solve this could be to try

```
usrid.append(row[0].strip())
```

which should strip whitespace when adding

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect but it's working like you want.

```
import argparse
import csv

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='What Product do you wish to know the price of?:')

parser.add_argument('csvFileName',metavar='f', type=str,
                   help='a csv file with , as delimiter')
parser.add_argument('item1',  type=str,
                   help='a first item')
parser.add_argument('item2',  type=str,
                   help='a second item')

args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.csvFileName) as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    listOfProduct = []
    #Fetch csv
    for row in readCSV:
        item = (row[0].replace(' ', ''), row[1].replace(' ', ''), row[2].replace(' ', ''))  
        listOfProduct.append(item)

    #Find all user corresponding with product
    item1found = [product for product in listOfProduct if product[2] == args.item1]
    item2found = [product for product in listOfProduct if product[2] == args.item2]

    allUserProducts = []    
    #Find item1 that corresponding with item2
    for item in item1found:
        (userId, price, product) = item
        otherUserProducts = [product for product in item2found if product[0] == userId]
        otherUserProducts.append(item)

        allUserProducts.append(otherUserProducts)

    for userProducts in allUserProducts:
        totalPrice = 0

        for product in userProducts:
            (userId, price, product) = product
            totalPrice += float(price)

        print '(' + str(userId) + ')','(' + str(totalPrice)+ ')'
```